# getting data from PHP file with json is failing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I can't get each data from PHP file, i'm always having AJAX failure, i tried many things, and looked for some pages for this problem but i can't find any solution, this is where i came last.
This is my jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
$('a[class="someclass"]').click(function(){

   var somedata = $(this).attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "foo.php",
      data: {"id": somedata}, 
      dataType:"json",

      success: function(data){
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#data1").html(data[0]);
         $("#data2").html(data[1]);
         $("#data3").html(data[2]);
         $("#data4").html(data[3]);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("AJAX request was a failure");
      }
    });
    });
    });
});
```

This is my PHP file:

```
$data = $_POST['id'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"database");
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".$data."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  $jsondata1 = array($row['data1'], $row['data2'], $row['data3'],  $row['data4']); 

  echo json_encode($jsondata1);
 }
mysqli_close($con);
```

I think there is no need to share HTML file, but if you want i can share with you.
Thank You!

Comment: Ajax failure on sending or receiving?

Comment: receiving, no problem with sending. json is not working

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by concatenate, how can i do that?

Comment: How many rows does your query return?

Comment: Is `id` the primary key of the table?

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley i'm calling for one row.

Comment: @Musa yes it is, i think problem is with json

Comment: You should use `LIMIT 1` to ensure that your query returns one row. Then check the contents of `$row` and ensure that you're actually getting all the data you expect to see.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley i tried that but already there is one row in that table

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the array value in the loop and echo $jsondata1, so you are sending many different arrays with the echo inside the loop, try this code:

```
 $jsondata1 = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $jsondata1[] = array($row['data1'], $row['data2'], $row['data3'],  $row['data4']); 

 }

 echo json_encode($jsondata1);
```

Comment: He's not overwriting data, he's echoing multiple json objects which are not a valid json object.

Comment: i changed codes to these but it's still not working. Maybe problem is with jQuery

Comment: @KorhanYüzbaş can you show us the error you are getting? Try checking your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault();` is a problem. `e` is not defined and if it was the default action would have already occurred by the time the success function was called. Try

```
$('a[class="someclass"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var somedata = $(this).attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "foo.php",
      data: {"id": somedata}, 
      dataType:"json",

      success: function(data){
         $("#data1").html(data[0]);
         $("#data2").html(data[1]);
         $("#data3").html(data[2]);
         $("#data4").html(data[3]);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("AJAX request was a failure");
      }
    });
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: i changed it but still not working, maybe problem is with json

Comment: Could be, does your query return multiple rows?

Comment: just one row, i want to get each variable in PHP. 
What about;  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "foo.php",
      data: {"id": somedata}, 
      dataType:"json",

      success: function(data){
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#data1").html(data[0]);
         $("#data2").html(data[1]);
         $("#data3").html(data[2]);
         $("#data4").html(data[3]);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("AJAX request was a failure");
      }
    });
maybe problem with this part

Comment: i think this is the same code with mine, i dont see any difference except preventdefault. and it's still not working. i wrote like " $("#data1").html(data[0]);" but should i call it with jsondata1? or should i use it somehow?

Comment: Can you post the response from the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the complete response.
when you echo each encoded it will not work.
Do something like

```
$jsonArray = array();
while(){
    array_push($jsonArray, array($row['data1'], $row['data2']);
}
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're calling json_encode multiple times when what you need to be doing is assigning those intermediate variables to an array and encode that array using json encode for the return.

PHP:

```
$data = $_POST['id'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"database");
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".$data."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$jsondata1 = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $jsondata1[] = array($row['data1'], $row['data2'], $row['data3'],  $row['data4']); 
}
mysqli_close($con);

die(json_encode($jsondata1));
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var doc = $(document);
doc.on('click', 'a.someclass', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var somedata = $(this).attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "foo.php",
      data: {"id": somedata}, 
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data){
          $("#data1").html(data[0]);
          $("#data2").html(data[1]);
          $("#data3").html(data[2]);
          $("#data4").html(data[3]);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("AJAX request was a failure");
      }
  });
});
```

});